# Problemas al redireccionar y validar form en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

buenas! soy bastante nuevo con javascript y estoy teniendo un serio problema para validar y redireccionar los input. Este es mi codigo html:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <a href="index.html" class="back"><span></span> < </a>
</div>

<div class="flex-container-registro">
    <div class="cuadroAzul">
        <p>REGISTRATE<br/>
        Ahora crea tu codigo de seguridad</p>
    </div>

    <form class="registro" id="rCod" onsubmit="return registroCs()" >
        <input type="text" class="security"  maxlength="1" id="rCod1" required>
        <input type="text" class="security"  maxlength="1" id="rCod2" required>
        <input type="text" class="security"  maxlength="1" id="rCod3" required>
        <input type="text" class="security"  maxlength="1" id="rCod4" required>
    <div class="infoRegistro">
        <p>Recordalo, lo vas a necesitar siempre que necesites Cargar Saldo</p>
    </div>

    <input class="botonRegistro" type="submit" value="Continuar" id="ContinuarRegistro" >
    </form>
</div>
```

este es mi codigo js

```js
function registroCs(){
  cs1= document.getElementById("rCod1").value;
  cs2= document.getElementById("rCod2").value;
  cs3= document.getElementById("rCod3").value;
  cs4= document.getElementById("rCod4").value;
  
  if ( cs1.length > 1 || cs2.length > 1 || cs3.length > 1 || cs4.length > 1  ) {
   error= true;
  } else if (cs1 != "" && cs2 != "" && cs3 != "" && cs4 != ""){
   error= false;
  }

  if (error == false) {
   alert("a otro lado");
   document.location.href = "registro2.html";
   return true;
  }

 }
```

si alguno tiene idea de por que no me genera la redireccion a la siguiente pagina y puede compartila seria de gran ayuda

Comment: en esta linea del HTML el href no deberia ser "registro.html" osea sin el 2 <input class="botonRegistro" type="submit" href="registro2.html" value="Continuar" id="ContinuarRegistro" >

Comment: `error` es `true` cuando **NO** hay error? Por otro lado, esto esta bien `cs1 != ""`, pero `cs2.length != ""` está mal.. estás comparando el largo del texto (un  número) con un string vacío... Pero más allá de eso, qué es lo que estás esperando que haga? que redireccione sin enviar los datos del form? cuando ingresa qué?

Comment: Estas seguro de tus condiciones?. Primero dices que si la longitud es mayor que 1, vamos que **tienes un dato en algún campo** `error=false`, y la otra condición es que si el valor de cs1 no es vacio?. no es una incongluencia?, y con el resto lo mismo. Por un lado pides longitud>1 y por otro lado que longutud sea ""

Comment: modifique los condicionales que claramente estaban muy mal y limpie el codigo pero aun asi NO consegui demasiado. Gracias por las respuestas aunque un poco hostiles algunas jaja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He aquí un ejemplo. En el action debes colocar la pagina que va a procesar tu formulario y los `input` deben tener atributo `name`. Ahora bien, cuando haces la "redirección" en tu código usas una dirección de Html estático "registro2.html", no un script, entonces no está claro como piensas procesar los datos que ingresa el usuario en el form. Yo de momento usaré la url de abajo en mi action.

```
<form class="registro" id="rCod" action="http://jkorpela.fi/cgi-bin/echo.cgi" 
    onsubmit="return validar()" >
    <input type="text" class="security"  maxlength="1" id="rCod1" name="rCod1" required />
    <input type="text" class="security"  maxlength="1" id="rCod2" name="rCod2" required />
    <input type="text" class="security"  maxlength="1" id="rCod3" name="rCod3" required />
    <input type="text" class="security"  maxlength="1" id="rCod4"  name="rCod4" required />
    <div class="infoRegistro">
        <p>Recordalo, lo vas a necesitar siempre que necesites Cargar Saldo</p>
    </div>

    <input class="botonRegistro" type="submit" value="Continuar" id="ContinuarRegistro" />
</form>
```

En el Javascript haces la validación. Por lo que entendí de tus comentarios y código, los datos son válidos siempre y cuando se haya escrito algo.

```
function validar() {
    cs1 = document.getElementById("rCod1").value;
    cs2 = document.getElementById("rCod2").value;
    cs3 = document.getElementById("rCod3").value;
    cs4 = document.getElementById("rCod4").value;
    return cs1.trim() != "" && cs2.trim() != "" && cs3.trim() != "" && cs4.trim() != "";
}
```

Nota: Como la etiqueta form no tiene atributo `method`, lo está enviando por GET.

Comment: La respuesta es correcta. El formulario no tiene evento onclick, y la función de comprobación debe retornar `false`, no redirigir.

Comment: genere como me sugirieron en "onsubmit" pero aun asi habiendo modificado los condicionales y generando el envio mediante submit no me redirecciona cuando la funcionar retorna true  (significando que no tiene errores)

Comment: Dado que no hay return false en ningun lado, lo que hace ese codigo es intentar enviar el formulario pero lo hace mal porque los input no tienen name. Para validar y enviar un form, no necesitas redireccionar, le pones un atributo action al form, le pones name a los input y en el onsubmit validas, si retorna false entonces no lo envia, si retorna true, lo envia.